# Response Compression Middleware for ASP.NET Core ignored on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

i have a simple ASP.NET Core App and in the Startup.cs I added the Response Compression Middleware to get my responeses compressed by gzip - super easy.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddResponseCompression();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            var defaults = new { controller = "Views", action = nameof(ViewsController.Index) };
            routeBuilder.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}", defaults);
            routeBuilder.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", defaults);
        });
    }
```

On my local maschine when I start the App out of Visual Studio regardless of whether IISExpress or Project Command my responses are compressed.

[image]

Now I publish my ASP.NET Core App to Azure with the Publish-Command from Visual Studio as an "Azure App Service" every think works just like local only the compression not.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what i missed?

---UPDATE---

Ok, i created a empty .Net Core Web Application with Visual Studio. I edit the Startup.cs to look like this, and put a simple index.html in the wwwroot folder. Than i right click the project and choose the deploy option. I created a new profile with a new Resourcegroup, new Plan and a new AppService.

here is the result: http://gzipapptest.azurewebsites.net/index.html But chrome/fiddler show's no gzip - maybe it because of the company-proxy can u try the website?

Thanks, iBot

```
    public class Startup
{
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCompression();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

}

Comment: I find it works in your  supplied site. I will update my answer.

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more conummities who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I test it with you mentioned code, it works correctly on my side. And it is very odd that you mentioned sceenshot that the remote address: `127.0.0.1:8888.` If it is possible please have a try to create a new WebApp and deploy it.

[image]

**Updated:**

It also works in your WebApp, you could refer to the screen. If you don't see the gzip in the response header, I assume that it received from the cache.

[image]

**Received from cache**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. The Remote Adresse looks like this, because i am behind a proxy, but i also tested without the proxy - makes no difference.

I also tried to create a new Azure App Service -> same problem :(

Comment: Have tried with a new created WebApp?  If it is possible, would mind sharing the demo code that could reproduce it?

Comment: i will try to make sample app and reproduce it. If the problem persists then I share the code.

Comment: Thanks Tom, i belive our company-proxy cheat on me and i have to test it with a none company PC without any proxy-settings. Probably it works the whole time just like you said. Thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however, if anyone else is having this issue and you are using the ASP.NET Core In-Process Hosting model on IIS, you must **also** install the Dynamic Content Compression feature in Server Manager --> Web Server --> Performance.